# UV4L custom webpages?

Tags: web-server, uv4l

I am trying to build custom webpage supporting uv4l webrtc. following the document at - [uv4l server](http://www.linux-projects.org/documentation/uv4l-server/)  i edited  /etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf (i am using USB camera) as follows

```
  ### serving custom Web pages only:
 server-option = --enable-www-server=yes
 server-option = --www-root-path=/usr/share/uv4l/www/
 server-option = --www-index-file=index.html
 server-option = --www-port=8888
```

I also created a index.html at /usr/share/uv4l/www/. Restarted service uv4l_raspicam . Now when i connect to http://rasp:8888/   i dont see my custom webpage loading.

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart `uv4l_uvc`,not `uv4l_raspicam`, for USB webcams.